# Rails 4: chart is not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, highcharts, chartkick

`chartkick` is integrated into a Rails 4 app. In `gemfile`, there added:

```
gem 'chartkick'
gem 'highcharts'
gem 'groupdate'
```

A simple action `common_chart` is defined as:

```
def common_chart
  @data_set = PaymentRequest.all
end
```

Here is `common_chart.html.erb`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <% line_chart @data_set.group('request_date').count, discrete: true %> 
</div>
```

A link is embeded on main page as:

```
<%= link_to 'PR Dashboard Report', common_chart_payment_requests_path(), class: BUTTONS_CLS['block-info'] %>
```

However when clicking `PR Dashboard Report`, there is nothing showing on the screen. No chart at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<% line_chart @data_set.group('request_date').count, discrete: true %>
```

To:

```
<%= line_chart @data_set.group('request_date').count, discrete: true %>
```

`<% %>` shows nothing, `<%= %>` shows output.

Comment: What a dumb mistake! Somehow the = sign was removed without notice. Thanks.